# find the smallest number of n integers

Tags: c, integer, min

C Programming Beginner.
I don't understand why this code doesn't work. The numbers I get as answers for min and max are 2686672 and 4525824. Can anyone explain please? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int array[20], i, x, y;
    int max, min;

    printf("Please enter number of integers to be checked\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for (y = 0; y <= x; y++) {
        printf("Please enter your numbers\n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }

    min = array[0];
    max = array[0];

    for (y = 0; y <= x; y++) {
        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        } else if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%d is the min and %d is the max", min, max);
}
```

Comment: always check the returned value from scanf() and family of functions, to assure the input/conversion operation(s) was successful.

Comment: what happens if the number of integers to check is > 20?   Writing past the end of the buffer.  I.E. undefined behavior, which can lead to anything including a seg fault event.

Comment: the numbers are being entered into 'i', they should be entered into array[y]

Comment: regarding this line: 'for (y = 0; y <= x; y++) {' the term y<=x will result in one more integer being requested than the user said would be available.  And if 'x' was 20 would result in writing past the end of the array[] .   A better way to write this line would be: 'for (y = 0; y < x; y++) {' which would ask for the right number of inputs;

Answer (score 2):

Your section at

```
for (y=0;y<=x;y++){
        printf ("Please enter your numbers\n");
        scanf ("%d",&i);
        }
```

Has several issues.  First, you're storing the value in i each time; that will get overwritten the next time through the loop.  Second, you want < instead of <= as you will otherwise ask for too many numbers.  (You should also check that the user asked for <= 20 numbers).

I think you want:

```
for (y=0;y< x;y++){
        printf ("Please enter your numbers\n");
        scanf ("%d",&array[y]);
        }
```

Comment: Minor: Check both ends `1 <= x <= 20`.

Comment: @chux, that will not work because array offsets start with 0 and a 20 entry array has a max offset of 19  so the suggested code is correct.  Although the returned value from scanf() needs to be checked to assure a valid value was successfully entered.  (and if not successful, display an error message, decrement the loop counter so the input/conversion will be tried again.

Comment: @user3629249 The comment "Check both ends `1 <= x <= 20`" applies to `x` which is the number of integers, not to the index `y` of the array `array`.  As @Foon correctly commented "check that the user asked for <= 20 numbers", additional could have advise to check that `1 <= x`, for entering 0 or negative numbers of integers leads to UB.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't storing the values that you read into i in your array when you have the loop asking for the numbers to be entered.

Later, your are indexing array with i, but the loop counter is y - so i is never changing (nor is it necessarily a valid index, since it holds the last value that was read via scanf).

Check your code again to make sure you actually store the values you read into an array, and then check what you are using for array indices when computing the max and min.

Answer (score 1):

you are never storing the numbers into the array. You overwrite the number the user enters on each pass. You therefore end up with garbage data at the end, whatever happened to be initialized into max and min.

```
 for (y=0;y<=x;y++){
        printf ("Please enter your numbers\n");
        scanf ("%d",&i);
        array[y] = i;
        }
```

at least this way there will be something in the array locations to compare with in your Max/Min Logic later on.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

write a loop to dump out the array after its entered - just so you can be sure you get the right stuff

```
for(i = 0 ; i < x; i++)
{
 printf("%d\n", array[i];
}
```

Also (as others have said) your loop boundaries need to be < not <=.  A 10 element array has elements numbered 0 - 9